# Инкапсуляция

Tags: c++

Есть код:

```
class _class {
private:
    int val;
public:
    _class() {
        val = 0;
    }
    _class(int i) {
        val = i;
    }

    int get(_class &ob) {
        return ob.val;  // почему свойство val доступно? "ob" же это объект
                        // и свойство "val" у него private ^_^
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    _class ob, ob1(10);
    cout << ob.get(ob1) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Так же произойдёт если я в методе "get" тупо создам объект класса "_class" и попробую достать переменную "val", то без проблем достанет. Я чего-то не понимаю?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так и должно быть. private действует на уровне класса, а не отдельного объекта. Он не ограничивает доступ к членам других объектов своего класса.

Answer (score 3):

Атрибуты приватны у класса, это значит что эти атрибуты не доступны нигде кроме методов класса и его друзей. `_class::_get` - метод класса `_class`, значит приватные атрибуты класса `_class` доступны внутри этого метода, что мы, собственно, и видим.